# How to implement a custom binary protocol using these rules?

Tags: python, sockets, struct, binary-data

I am trying to send binary data to a server that gives me back a response on doing so. The rules seems understandable to someone who is familiar with python but I am new to python and socket programming using struct. So the documentation states this:

There is an 8 byte header that has a 32 bit integer for the request tag and a 32 bit integer for the command. The type is uint32. The buffersize depends on the type of command.

Some commands take arguments and they are sent in tandem with the command message header directly after the header with no padding. The size of the arguments buffer is dictated by the command type.

So I connected to the server and now I tried to package to values and send it like that but I dont know if I am doing it right.

```py
import socket
import struct

# Create a TCP/IP socket

from protlib import hexdump

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('localhost', 4200)
sock.connect(server_address)

values = (23, 42)
packer = struct.Struct('i i ')
packed_data = packer.pack(*values)

# Send data
sock.sendall(packed_data)

while True:
    raw_data = sock.recv(1024)
    unpacked_data = struct.unpack('>i i', raw_data)
    print(unpacked_data)
    sock.close()
```

If someone can just point me in the right direction and provide some guidance I will read more on it.

Comment: `import self as self`? You're packing 2 *int*s, which is 8 byte. That the header. Now you have to also pack the data, but it's hard to tell without knowing the protocol.

Comment: Yea you have a point let me add more in a bit about the protocol.

Comment: Added a bit more about info on the protocol. But also the command ID i want to send is 1.

Comment: My 2 cents. If you're going through this path for real, you would like to use https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/

Comment: Note that the line after your `sock.recv(1024)` line seems to assume that you'll receive all of the bytes of exactly one message at the same time; but TCP is a streaming protocol and doesn't know about your message boundaries, so it's entirely possible that you won't get all of the bytes at the same time (i.e. you might get the first 3 bytes in the first `recv()` call and then the remaining bytes in the next `recv()` call, or etc).... or you might receive the bytes from more than one message in a single `recv()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found the errror and was able to get the response I wanted with the server. The error was with

packer = struct.Struct('i i ') // Needed to format it like ('! i i')

and 
raw_data = sock.recv(1024)
    unpacked_data = struct.unpack('>i i', raw_data) // Needed to add ! not >
    print(unpacked_data)
    sock.close()

also I wrote a simple unpacker that helped me to unpack it the proper way

def data_unpacking(data):
    tag, code = struct.unpack('!ii', data[:8])
    return tag, code, data[8:]

then called the function in main with the parameter raw_data